# Language of reference entries for sources in a foreign language

Tags: citations

Must the entries in a list of sources match the language of their respective sources? For example, for a non-English text, may one include words and phrases such as "In", "volume", "edited by So-and-so and So-and-so", "translated by", pages xx-yy"?

Answer (score 5):

Citations follow templates, e.g.,

> A, B, & C (YYYY) Title. In BookTitle, volume X, pages xx-yy.

To cite a particular work, you fill-in the place holders, e.g., A, B, C, YYYY,  Title, BookTitle, X, xx, and yy. Hence, words such as "In", "volume", and "pages" can remain in English.

When a template does not specify how to include translations of titles/booktitles, I think it is reasonable to include bracketed translations, e.g., original title (translated title).